# Advantages of braintree gem over ActiveMerchant braintree gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, braintree, activemerchant

I'm in the process of switching from a gateway implemented in ActiveMerchant to the Braintree gateway. I noticed that there was a braintree gateway in ActiveMerchant and there is also a braintree_ruby gem by braintree.

Since our system is already designed around active merchant, there will be quite a bit of refactoring needed to switch over to the Braintree gem.

Is there anything you can't do with the ActiveMerchant Braintree gem that you can in the Braintree gem?

What advantages does using the Braintree gem have over the ActiveMerchant Braintree gem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. You can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) if you have more questions.</sub>

The ActiveMerchant gem uses an outdated integration method to integrate with Braintree. It may have different PCI compliance implications than a [v.zero integration](https://www.braintreepayments.com/v.zero), as well as lacking new features of the Braintree API.

Until ActiveMerchant is upgraded, I'd suggest using the Braintree gem directly.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: I work at Braintree.
The ActiveMerchant gem now supports nonces with Braintree, so as long as you pass a `payment_method_nonce` instead of a credit card number when creating a transaction or payment method, the PCI compliance implications are the same as a direct Braintree integration using nonces. However, ActiveMerchant does not support all features Braintree offers, such as recurring billing (https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/wiki/gatewayfeaturematrix#features-by-gateway).

Comment: @JordanBrough see Jessica's comment.